# Probability of a triangle inside a square

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

**Question**

If we have the square with vertices at the $4$ corners of $(0,1)^2$, and we choose a random point $z$ inside the square, the triangle is between $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $z$, what is the CDF and PDF of the random variable $A_T$ representing the area of the triangle?

**My Attempt**

I think that $A_{T}= \frac{b*h}{2}$, in this case $b= 1-0 =1$ and so this would give us: $A_{T}=\frac{h}{2}$

We then use this substitution to derive:

1. **CDF:** $P(A_{T}  \leq x )= P( \frac{h}{2} \leq x ) = P(h \leq 2x )$
2. **PDF:** $P(A_{T}=x)=P(h=2x)$

How can I find these probability?

Comment: **Hint:** the point $z$ is chosen uniformly (continuous uniform distribution). So it would be more useful to express the area in terms of the point $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x, y) = z$.  The triangle has a base of $1$ and a height of $y$, so thus an area of $A_T = \frac{1}{2} y$.  Note that $A_T$ does not depend on $x$, only on $y$.

Your question does not explicitly say what is meant by “a random point”, but I assume that it's a continuous uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$.  Since $A_T$ is just a constant multiple of a uniformly-distributed variable ($y$), it itself is uniformly-distributed, but on the interval $(0, \frac{1}{2})$.

You should be able to work out the CDF and PDF from there.